# Detect string contains a number then insert a space before it

Tags: java, regex, string

Consider I have such String `"Abcd123"`, I need to first detect if my string contains numbers (0-9) or not, then insert a space before the first number so my final String is `"Abcd 123"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
String str = "Abcd123";
if (str.replaceAll("\\D", "").length() > 0) {  // check if the string contain numbers
    str = str.replaceFirst("\\d", " $0");      // if yes put a space before the first degit
}
```

**Output**

```
Abcd 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple logic :

```
    String str = "Abcd123";
    String newStr = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
            newStr = newStr + " " + str.substring(i);
            break;
        } else {
            newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

Here we iterate over each character in the string and break from the loop as soon as we find the *first* digit.

Output :

> Abcd 123